# Unable to update kernel

Tags: kernel, segmentation-fault

I kept getting a  kernel panic (not syncing. No init found) trying to boot my Ubuntu Server, so I burned the latest version of Ubuntu Server to a CD and booted (used option boot to fist disk) to try to install a new kernel as suggested in an [Ubuntu forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228437&page=2).

All goes well until I try to perform a `sudo apt-get upgrade` and get a bunch of Segmentation fault (core dumped) and other errors as you can see below...

Is there anyway I can remove these old kernels and I install a new clean kernel? Or is this a lost cause and do I need to do a clean install?

```
david@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-31-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apparmor apport apt apt-transport-https apt-utils binutils
  cpp-4.8 curl deb-multimedia-keyring dkms fuse g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base
  grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common initscripts isc-dhcp-client
  isc-dhcp-common libaccountsservice0 libapparmor-perl libapparmor1
  libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12 libasan0 libatomic1 libcups2 libcurl3
  libcurl3-gnutls libdrm2 libfuse2 libgcc-4.8-dev libgomp1 libitm1
  libldap-2.4-2 libnuma1 libnvpair1 libpam-systemd libpolkit-agent-1-0
  libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpython2.7
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.4-minimal
  libpython3.4-stdlib libquadmath0 libssl1.0.0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6
  libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0 libtasn1-6 libtsan0 libudev1 libuutil1
  libzfs2 libzpool2 linux-firmware linux-libc-dev openssl patch
  plexmediaserver policykit-1 ppp python-pkg-resources python-requests
  python-six python-urllib3 python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3-apport
  python3-problem-report python3-update-manager python3.4 python3.4-minimal
  rsyslog spl spl-dkms systemd-services sysv-rc sysvinit-utils udev
  unattended-upgrades unrar update-manager-core wpasupplicant zfs-dkms zfs-doc
  zfsutils
93 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 3 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 205 MB of archives.
After this operation, 449 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ wheezy/main deb-multimedia-keyring all                                                                                                                                   des all 0.82.1ubuntu2.3 [25.5 kB]
Get:92 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse unrar amd6
[...SNIPPED...]                                                                                                                                                             4 1:5.0.10-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 [117 kB]
Get:93 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main wpasupplicant am                                                                                                                                                             d64 2.1-0ubuntu1.3 [749 kB]
Fetched 205 MB in 1min 33s (2,198 kB/s)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
(Reading database ... 144747 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic (3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-30-generic /                                                                                                                                                             boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz                                                                                                                                                             -3.16.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-30-generic /b                                                                                                                                                             oot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 139
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-31-generic (3.16.0-31.43~14.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.16.0-31-generic: No such file o                                                                                                                                                             r directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-31-generic /                                                                                                                                                             boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz                                                                                                                                                             -3.16.0-31-generic
/var/lib/dkms/spl/0.6.3/build/configure: line 546:  6397 Illegal instruction                                                                                                                                                                  (core dumped) rmdir conf$$.dir 2> /dev/null
config/config.guess: line 1:  6520 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) exit
/var/lib/dkms/spl/0.6.3/build/configure: line 2947:  6569 Illegal instruction                                                                                                                                                                  (core dumped) rmdir .tst 2> /dev/null
configure: error: in `/var/lib/dkms/spl/0.6.3/build':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/spl/0.6.3/build/make.log for more information.
/var/lib/dkms/zfs/0.6.3/build/configure: line 546:  7010 Illegal instruction                                                                                                                                                                  (core dumped) rmdir conf$$.dir 2> /dev/null
config/config.guess: line 1:  7151 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) exit
/var/lib/dkms/zfs/0.6.3/build/configure: line 3119:  7200 Illegal instruction                                                                                                                                                                  (core dumped) rmdir .tst 2> /dev/null
configure: error: in `/var/lib/dkms/zfs/0.6.3/build':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/zfs/0.6.3/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-31-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-31-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.16.0-31-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_p3H5nU/lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_p3H5nU/lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 139
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-31-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic (3.16.0-33.44~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-33-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-33-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-33-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-33-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-33-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-33-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-33-generic
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 139
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-31-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this from the tty type in this:

```
      sudo apt-get install kernel-packages
      sudo apt-get install x86_amd64-efi_ amd64-efi
      sudo apt-get install aptitude
      sudo aptitude x86_amd64-efi_
      sudo apt-get install -f
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it might work fine this way.